# Connection pool exhausted error in Jetty Server

Tags: java, jetty

I am getting `Connection pool exhausted - try increasing 'maxPoolSize' and/or 'borrowConnectionTimeout on the DataSourceBean` when I'm executing a test for 300 Vusers. can anyone tell me how exactly this errors occurs I mean for what reasons and how can we solve this...??
Do I need to increase the `maxpoolsize` of **app.properties** file ?
or can anyone explain what is a `connection pool` ? as I'm not a tester I don't have much knowledge on db side.

Waiting for your Response/answers

Thank You

Comment: How are you connecting to your datasource? Post that please.

Comment: That error is not from Jetty, its likely that the errors is coming from your DataSource, your connection pool lib, or something similar.  Like @Stefan said, we'd need more information about your setup to know how to help.